# How to setup a constantbuffer in sharpDx DirectX11

Tags: c#, directx, buffer, handler, shader

I'm trying to access a Uniform Paramter and change it's Value in SharpDx.
I've already posted this on the SharpDx board but I did not get a Reply so I'm trying my luck here.
Through google I found this example http://timjones.tw/blog/archive/2011/03/08/marshalling-c-structures-into-directd--cbuffers-using but the structure of DataBox has changed within the latest SharpDx version.
Now its (intPr, int,int) not like it was used in the link

```
var dataBox = new DataBox(0, 0, _dataStream);
```

this is what I've tried 
    namespace MiniTri
    {
        /// 
        ///   SharpDX port of SharpDX-MiniTri Direct3D 11 Sample
        /// 
        ///

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct Variables
    {
        public float R, G, B, A;
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static unsafe void Main()
        {
            var form = new RenderForm("SharpDX - MiniTri Direct3D 11 Sample TEST");

            // SwapChain description
            var desc = new SwapChainDescription()
            {
                BufferCount = 1,
                ModeDescription =
                    new ModeDescription(form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height,
                                        new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
                IsWindowed = true,
                OutputHandle = form.Handle,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
                Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
            };

            // Create Device and SwapChain
            Device device;
            SwapChain swapChain;
            Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.None,    desc, out device, out swapChain);
            var context = device.ImmediateContext;

            // Ignore all windows events
            var factory = swapChain.GetParent<Factory>();
            factory.MakeWindowAssociation(form.Handle, WindowAssociationFlags.IgnoreAll);

            // New RenderTargetView from the backbuffer
            var backBuffer = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0);
            var renderView = new RenderTargetView(device, backBuffer);

            // Compile Vertex and Pixel shaders
            var vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniTri.fx", "VS", "vs_4_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None);
            var vertexShader = new VertexShader(device, vertexShaderByteCode);

            var pixelShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniTri.fx", "PS", "ps_4_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None);
            var pixelShader = new PixelShader(device, pixelShaderByteCode);



            //Layout Color
            // Layout from VertexShader input signature
            var layout = new InputLayout(
                device,
                ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(vertexShaderByteCode),
                new[]
                    {
                        new InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32_Float, 0, 0),
                        new InputElement("COLOR", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 0, 1)
                    });

            // Instantiate Vertex buiffer from vertex data
            var vertices = Buffer.Create(device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, new[]
                                  {
                                      new Vector3(-0.9f, -0.2f, 0.0f),
                                      new Vector3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f),
                                      new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), 
                                      new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f)

                                  });
            // Instantiate Vertex buiffer from vertex data
            var verticesColors = Buffer.Create(device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, new[]
                                  {
                                      new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
                                  });
            var triangles = Buffer.Create(device, BindFlags.IndexBuffer, new short[]
                                  {
                                      1,
                                      2,
                                      3
                                  });



            // Prepare All the stages
            context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = layout;
            context.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleList;
            context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding[]
            {
              new VertexBufferBinding(vertices,12, 0),
              new VertexBufferBinding(verticesColors,16, 0)
            }

            );
            context.InputAssembler.SetIndexBuffer(triangles, Format.R16_UInt, 0);
            context.VertexShader.Set(vertexShader);
            context.Rasterizer.SetViewports(new Viewport(0, 0, form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height, 0.0f, 1.0f));
            context.PixelShader.Set(pixelShader);
            context.OutputMerger.SetTargets(renderView);




            //In HLSL global variables are considered uniform by default.

            //It's also settled that a variable coming out of the vertex shader stage for example is varying (HLSL doesn't need this keyword at all!).

            //Note that GLSL keywords uniform/varying are inherited from RSL (RenderMan shading language).


            //Uniform Parameter 
            // UniformHandle testFarbeHandle = pixelShader.GetUniformParam("TestFarbe");
            // pixelShader.SetUniform(testFarbeHandle, Handle.Color.Black);

            //Effect handle = new Effect(device, pixelShaderByteCode, EffectFlags.None);
            //handle.GetVariableByName("TestFarbe").AsVector().Set(Color.Red);

            var getUniform = new Buffer(device, new BufferDescription
            {
                Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
                SizeInBytes = sizeof(Variables),
                BindFlags = BindFlags.ConstantBuffer
            });

            var cb = new Variables();
            cb.R = 1.0f;
            cb.G = 0.0f;
            cb.B = 0.0f;
            cb.A = 1.0f;
            var data = new DataStream(sizeof(Variables), true, true);
            data.Write(cb);
            data.Position = 0;

            context.UpdateSubresource(new DataBox(data.PositionPointer, 0, 0), getUniform, 0);
            context.VertexShader.SetConstantBuffer(0, getUniform);
            // Main loop
            RenderLoop.Run(form, () =>
            {
                context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderView, Color.Black);

                context.DrawIndexed(3, 0, 0);
                swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
            });

            // Release all resources
            vertexShaderByteCode.Dispose();
            vertexShader.Dispose();
            pixelShaderByteCode.Dispose();
            pixelShader.Dispose();
            vertices.Dispose();
            layout.Dispose();
            renderView.Dispose();
            backBuffer.Dispose();
            context.ClearState();
            context.Flush();
            device.Dispose();
            context.Dispose();
            swapChain.Dispose();
            factory.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

But as I said since the DataBox has changed the line

```
context.UpdateSubresource(new DataBox(data, 0, 0), getUniform, 0);
```

The .Fx file looks like this

```
cbuffer Variables : register(b0){
 float4 TestFarbe;
} 
struct VS_IN
{
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float4 col : COLOR;
};

struct PS_IN
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 col : COLOR;

};

PS_IN VS( VS_IN input )
{
    PS_IN output = (PS_IN)0;

    output.pos = input.pos;

    output.col = input.col;

    return output;
}

float4 PS( PS_IN input ) : SV_Target
{

    return TestFarbe;
}
```

All I get is a Blackscreen. Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you get something rendered if you return a constant color in the pixel shader?

Comment: oh damn thanks I was kind of dumb ;) Of course it has to be context.PixelShader.SetConstantBuffer(0, getUniform);
Thank you very much!